# best practice or tools for stress test on a Tomcat application server and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, tomcat, java, stress-testing

I am using `Tomcat 6` application container for my web site. HTTP requests come from mobile phones and every time server receive a httprequest it opens `MySQL` connection, insert some data in it and then close it.
I want to know what is the number of  maximum simultaneously users that can send request to server and server also answer them.(in other words the the number that after that `Tomcat` or `MySQL` will be crash)
Is there any inexpensive way or tool for testing my server?

Answer (score 0):

I use jmeter. JMeter is capable to record traffic and after just replay it on several threads. Is a very good tool for stress testing and is FREE.

Also JMeter is capable to tell it what URI should access on your server.

Comment: what do you mean by record traffic? thanks

Comment: Reading and saving all commands what your users are sending to your app. Offcourse you need to do that in a controllable way if you have dynamic scripts, sessions etc.